# EmailComposeTask issue in WP8

Tags: c#, windows, windows-phone-8, windows-phone

I am working on a scenario where i need to send logs that i save in isolated storage file to an email from the button click event of a wp8 app. Here's how i intend to do it,

```
        private void BtnGetLogs_OnClick(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            try
            {
                var isoStore = IsolatedStorageFile.GetUserStoreForApplication();

                //Check if the isolated file exists
                if (isoStore.FileExists(LogFileName))
                {
                    Debug.WriteLine("The file exists!");

                    // Open the filestream to read the file
                    var isoStream = new IsolatedStorageFileStream(LogFileName, FileMode.Open, isoStore);

                    var reader = new StreamReader(isoStream);
                    string text = reader.ReadToEnd();
                    SendLogsToEmail(text.Substring(length));
         }
```

This is the function where i am sending an email,

```
        private void SendLogsToEmail(string body)
        {

            var emailComposeTask = new EmailComposeTask();
            {
                emailComposeTask.Subject = "Log file to mail";

                emailComposeTask.Body = body;

                emailComposeTask.To = "sample@gmail.com";
            };

            emailComposeTask.Show();
        }
```

I would like to give a background on this issue as well. This is purely a windows phone 8.0 project so i wont be able to send any attachments. That is the reason i am trying to read all the file contents and send it over the mail. Please note that this is work around solution for something i am working on. This is an edge case scenario where i am not able to fetch logs from IsoStoreSpy or any other tools because of OEM security issues. So in the app itself i have a button click event which reads the isolated storage file and sends a mail to the specified user.

Here's the problem, 
I get an ArgumentOutOfRangeException at  `emailComposeTask.Show();` and the error message is,

```
Specified argument was out of the range of valid values.
Parameter name: The size of input should not exceed 64K.
```

The log file is a pretty big file actually. Is there an elegant solution to this problem?

Answer (score 0):

The error is self explaining here, your are trying to set the email body to a text that is too long.

You better upload the logs somewhere like OneDrive.

Answer (score 0):

I encountered the same issue with my [NZ Topo Map app](http://www.windowsphone.com/en-nz/store/app/nz-topo-map/b861ab51-a68d-456f-9ae4-cbed66736b36) when emailing tracks as kml or gpx files. My solution was to create a simple online service that I first posted the file to via http. This service would store the file in an online location for me, then send the url to the file as a response back. I would then include a link to the file in the email rather than attaching the file.